# Parse a specified arithmetic type from string

Tags: c#, strings, parsing, .net

This class has the responsibility of parsing a string to one of the primitive types: `int`, `double`, `float`, `decimal`...

While creating it, I have noticed that **it'll be terribly ugly**.

It basically should perform a `TryParse` of each primitive type and return the first that returns true, along with the parsed value.

```
public static class PrimitiveParser
{
    public static bool TryParse(Type targetType, string sourceValue, out object result)
    {
        result = null;

        if (targetType == typeof(int))
        {
            int intResult;
            var parseResult = int.TryParse(sourceValue, out intResult);
            {
                result = intResult;
                return parseResult;
            }
        }
        if (targetType == typeof(double))
        {
            double doubleResult;
            var parseResult = double.TryParse(sourceValue, out doubleResult);
            {
                result = doubleResult;
                return parseResult;
            }
        }
        if (targetType == typeof(float))
        {
            float floatResult;
            var parseResult = float.TryParse(sourceValue, out floatResult);
            {
                result = floatResult;
                return parseResult;
            }
        }

        /// ...

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: As I am reading this it does not perform a TryParse of each primitive type and return the first that returns true.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd prefer to use a dictionary for this.

```
private delegate bool TryParseDelegate<T>(string text, out T value);

private static readonly Dictionary<Type, object> TryParsers = new Dictionary<Type, object>
{
    { typeof(int), (TryParseDelegate<int>)int.TryParse },
    { typeof(float), (TryParseDelegate<float>)float.TryParse },
    { typeof(double), (TryParseDelegate<double>)double.TryParse }
};
```

The `TryParse` method:

```
public static bool TryParse<T>(string value, out T returnValue)
{
    // Check if we have a parse method for T in the dictionary.
    object parserObj;
    if (TryParsers.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out parserObj))
    {
        TryParseDelegate<T> parser = (TryParseDelegate<T>)parserObj;
        return parser(value, out returnValue);
    }
    // If no, fallback to IConvertible.
    if (typeof(IConvertible).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
    {
        try
        {
            returnValue = (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
            return true;
        }
        catch { }
    }
    // No luck.
    returnValue = default(T);
    return false;
}
```

---

This approach support exensibility.
For example, imagine we have a class `A`:

```
public class A
{
    public static readonly A Zero = new A("Zero");
    public static readonly A One = new A("One");

    public readonly string Text;

    private A(string text)
    {
        Text = text;
    }

    public static bool TryParse(string text, out A value)
    {
        switch (text.ToLower())
        {
            case "zero":
                value = Zero;
                break;
            case "one":
                value = One;
                break;
            default:
                value = null;
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

Then the only thing you have to do is to append an item to the dictionary:

```
{ typeof(A), (TryParseDelegate<A>)A.TryParse }
```

Let's test it:

```
int i;
double d;
A a;

if (TryParse("123", out i))
    Console.WriteLine($"i={i}"); // Prints i=123
if (TryParse("123.456", out d))
    Console.WriteLine($"d={d}"); // Prints d=123.456
if (TryParse("ONE", out a))
    Console.WriteLine($"a={a}"); // Prints a=One
```

Answer (score 10):

You may be over thinking this, all the types have a common `IConvertible` implementation and you can use `Convert.ChangeType` to parse from a string.

```
public static bool TryParse<T>(string value, out T returnValue)
{
    returnValue = default(T);
    try
    {
        returnValue = (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
        return true;
    }
    catch { }

    return false;
}
```

Which you can call like this:

```
float output = 0.0f;
var val = TryParse("19.2", out output);
//val == true, output = 19.2
val = TryParse("puppies", out output);
//val == false, output = 0.0f (default(T))
```

As an added bonus, this works with any type that supports [`IConvertible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible(v=vs.110).aspx). See [`Convert.ChangeType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

The only thing I don't like about this approach is that it uses a `try`/`catch` to determine if the conversion is possible or not. This is very performant when the types are convertible but does suffer a performance penalty for the exception when the type is not convertible.

Comment: The interface definitely lacks a `CanConvert` method.

Comment: @t3chb0t I agree, although the designers probably recognized that `CanConvert` would have to do pretty much the same as above (attempt the conversion and fail) since it wouldn't be any less time-complex. I think a nicer addition would be the `TryConvert` which returns true/false and the value like all the `TryParse` methods on the primitive types. It may be possible to use `dynamic` in this situation and just call `TryParse` directly if the type is primitive (and not a pointer), but that may cost extra and I'm not sure how you'd call that without reflection (I don't think you can `(dynamic)T`.